# Spring tool suiteでMaven installエラー (Spring boot)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

Spring tool suiteでMaven install時にエラーが出てしまい、ビルドできず、どうすればよいのかわかりません。どうかお助けください。

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MyBootApp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:2.7.9 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be ava    ilable, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:resources (default-resources) @ MyBootApp ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ MyBootApp ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 4 source files to C:\Users\yoshi\Documents\workspace-sts-3.9.2.RELEASE\MyBootApp\target\classes    
[ERROR] C:\Users\yoshi\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.0.6.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-5.0.6.RELEASE.ja    rの読込みエラーです。invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] C:\Users\yoshi\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.2.17.Final\hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar    の読込みエラーです。invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ MyBootApp ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\yoshi\Documents\workspace-sts-3.9.2.RELEASE\MyBootApp\src\te    st\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ MyBootApp ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\yoshi\Documents\workspace-sts-3.9.2.RELEASE\MyBootApp\target\test-cla    sses
[ERROR] C:\Users\yoshi\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.0.6.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-5.0.6.RELEASE.ja    rの読込みエラーです。invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] C:\Users\yoshi\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.2.17.Final\hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar    の読込みエラーです。invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) @ MyBootApp ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running com.kuwa.springboot.MyBootAppApplicationTests
23:00:52.136 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner - SpringJUnit4ClassRun    ner constructor called with [class com.kuwa.springboot.MyBootAppApplicationTests]
(省略）

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.2.RELEASE)

2018-07-08 23:00:55.375  INFO 24768 --- [           main] c.k.s.MyBootAppApplicationTests          : Starting My    BootAppApplicationTests on DESKTOP-2H6JNOI with PID 24768 (started by yoshi in C:\Users\yoshi\Documents\workspac    e-sts-3.9.2.RELEASE\MyBootApp)
2018-07-08 23:00:55.380  INFO 24768 --- [           main] c.k.s.MyBootAppApplicationTests          : No active p    rofile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-07-08 23:00:55.565  INFO 24768 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Refreshing     org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@496bc455: startup date [Sun Jul 08 23:00:55     JST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-07-08 23:01:00.981  WARN 24768 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception e    ncountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.Unsatis    fiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'heloController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed throug    h field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qu    alifying bean of type 'com.kuwa.springboot.repositories.MyDataRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean wh    ich qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Auto    wired(required=true)}
2018-07-08 23:01:01.013  INFO 24768 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled    .
2018-07-08 23:01:01.599 ERROR 24768 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field repository in com.kuwa.springboot.HeloController required a bean of type 'com.kuwa.springboot.repositories    .MyDataRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.kuwa.springboot.repositories.MyDataRepository' in your configuration.

2018-07-08 23:01:01.622 ERROR 24768 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exce    ption while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@7d    c0f706] to prepare test instance [com.kuwa.springboot.MyBootAppApplicationTests@69e308c6]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwa    reContextLoaderDelegate.java:125) ~[spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java    :108) ~[spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletT    estExecutionListener.java:190) ~[spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutio    nListener.java:132) ~[spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246) ~[sp    ring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:2    27) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunn    er.java:289) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]    
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:    291) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246    ) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)     [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClas    sCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassC    allbacks.java:70) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) [sp    ring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365) [surefire-junit4-2.21.0.    jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273) [surefire-junit    4-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238) [surefire-junit4-    2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159) [surefire-junit4-2.21.0.j    ar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:379) [sur    efire-booter-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:340) [surefire-booter-    2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:125) [surefire-booter-2.21.0.jar:    2.21.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:413) [surefire-booter-2.21.0.jar:2.2    1.0]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'helo    Controller': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframewor    k.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.kuwa.springboot.repositories.MyDa    taRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations:     {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.i    nject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring    -beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValu    es(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowir    eCapableBeanFactory.java:1348) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowir    eCapableBeanFactory.java:578) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireC    apableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java    :317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanR    egistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[s    pring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spr    ing-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultList    ableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractAp    plicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:55    0) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEAS    E.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2    .RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.ja    r:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:13    9) ~[spring-boot-test-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(Default    CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwa    reContextLoaderDelegate.java:117) ~[spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.kuwa    .springboot.repositories.MyDataRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candi    date. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultList    ableBeanFactory.java:1509) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableB    eanFactory.java:1104) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBea    nFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.i    nject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 45 common frames omitted

[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 10.708 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.kuwa.spri    ngboot.MyBootAppApplicationTests
[ERROR] contextLoads(com.kuwa.springboot.MyBootAppApplicationTests)  Time elapsed: 0.044 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'helo    Controller': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframewor    k.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.kuwa.springboot.repositories.MyDa    taRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations:     {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.kuwa    .springboot.repositories.MyDataRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candi    date. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   MyBootAppApplicationTests.contextLoads ≫ IllegalState Failed to load Applicati...
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 25.612 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-07-08T23:01:02+09:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 34M/210M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "pom.xml" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) on proj    ect MyBootApp: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\yoshi\Documents\workspace-sts-3.9.2.RELEASE\MyBootApp\target\surefire-reports f    or the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].    dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

pom.xml
    
    
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        4.0.0

```
    <groupId>com.kuwa.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyBootApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>MyBootApp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency -->

        <!--  dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-groovy-templates</artifactId>
        </dependency-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    </project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

すみません。こっちのエラーですね。

```
> [ERROR]
> C:\Users\yoshi\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.0.6.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jarの読込みエラーです。invalid
> LOC header (bad signature) [ERROR]
> C:\Users\yoshi\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.2.17.Final\hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jarの読込みエラーです。invalid
> LOC header (bad signature)
```

[Mavenリポジトリのローカルキャッシュを削除で解決](https://qiita.com/ASHITSUBO/items/0d30c1ddf476d2ec96b7) するという記事がありました。
以下をお試しください。

> C:\Users\yoshi\.m2\repository 配下のフォルダを全て削除し、
>   Mavenプロジェクト右クリック → Maven → Update Maven Project... からpom.xmlを反映し直す。

Comment: ありがとうございます！！問題解消しました！！　ちなみに、今回の記事に行きつくには、どのように検索等されましたでしょうか。

Comment: [ERROR]が表示されている行を確認し、そこに`invalid LOC header (bad signature)` というメッセージがあったので、このメッセージはどういう意味かなと思い、ググりました。その結果、記事がみつかりました。

Comment: なるほどです。。ありがとうございます。